# How to add the SphinxSE Plugin to a Percona XtraDB Cluster?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, percona

Our system currently has a Percona 5.6 XtraDb cluster with 3 database nodes and an ha proxy server configured.

This entire setup is working great.

We need to add the SphinxSE plugin to our already running server to utilize the search capabilities as a storage engine on the MySQL cluster.

I've searched several blogs/percona/and attempted multipl search queries to figure out how to add SphinxSE to an existing server. All the references that I have found show you have to build SphinxSE WITH MySQL. Perhaps my google fu is off, and I'm not searching for the right terms.

Any direction on how to add this to the Percona XtraDb cluster would be most helpeful.

Comment: This is also my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, according to Percona, you don't.

The best solution is to create a Sphinx server that indexes the tables you want and then query those indexes are part of your code.